# How to know /guess which series(out of 100) will give better forecast before applying any time series model and without plotting each series?

Tags: forecasting

I have More than 100 variables which are to be forecast. But before applying any time series model and plotting series, How can I guess that a particular series may have a higher chance of getting good forecast.

Comment: Good question! I guess univariate forecast are good or bad based on how strongly a time series follows some (repetitive) pattern. Usually the pattern is discovered by fitting a model or at least looking at the spectrum. I think you are looking for a metric kind of a thing which can give an idea whether the series has a strong pattern. Don't know about any such metric but in any case the sample variance would definitely help. If the variance is high then it is more likely that the prediction of series wouldn't be very good. Although the forecast of expected value may still be good.

Comment: assuming of course that the series are all stationary. Otherwise, sample variance can be misleading.

Comment: I am trying with the approach of Coefficient of variation that may give the better idea of pattern than the sample variance. But I would like to know the any Perfect metric that would be better than the Coefficient of variation. Thanks Dayne

Answer (score 0):

You don't guess, you conduct tests to understand the nature of series and then decide the model. For instance, you check to see is there strong seasonality and no trend ? If yes then use seasonal Naive model. Is the data almost like white noise? If yes, then use random walk model. Is there significant autocorrelation ? Use AR or ARIMA model. Is the data intermittent? Use Cronston model. Is there seasonality and autocorrelation both? Use seasonal ARIMA model. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Actually I have the idea  to apply the model to data by looking at its pattern  but it would be great if we know before applying the model to data . If you know any metric that can tell the pattern and chance of  good forecast , please share